# Passing feed URLs with "&" to fetch_feed()?

Tags: rss, feed, simplepie

How do I pass feed URLs with `&` in the URL to `fetch_feed()`?

The feed is not parsed correctly if there is a `&` in the feed URL. Actually it works in the example I gave, but now I'm populating the feeds array dynamically with this code :

```
$rss_subscriptions = array();
$terms = get_terms('news_rss','hide_empty=0');
$count = count($terms);
if($count > 0){
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        array_push($rss_subscriptions,$term->description);
    }
}
```

The RSS feeds URLs are stored in the descriptions of the taxonomy `news_rss` terms. Somehow in this code, passing `&` into the array makes the `fetch_feed($array)` not work.

---

#### Original question: fetch_feed() on multiple feeds, how to pass the feeds array properly ?

Hi, this is too weird, perhaps someone can explain what is going on here.

Why does this :

```
$feeds = array('http://www.mysite.com/feed','http://www.coolsite.net/feed');
$result = fetch_feed($feeds);
```

return a different result than this :

```
$result = fetch_feed(array('http://www.mysite.com/feed','http://www.coolsite.net/feed'));
```

Actually, the second example works, the first one returns feed items, but for some reason they are not the last ones...

I want to find a way to populate the feeds array dynamically, that's why I'd like something like the first example better.

Comment: It would help if you provided example of specific public (if available) URL that causes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment above, I think it is probably to do with the `&` being converted into `&amp;` or `&#038;`.

I had this problem and ended up solving it by running the URL though wp_specialchars_decode before passing it to fetch_feed.

I'd suggest you try this (although so much time has passed that I'm really writing this for people who stumble across this page via Google as I did).

I've written up my problem over here, in case it helps:
http://scratch99.com/wordpress/development/fetch_feed-url-problem/

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still wondering about this:

If you're using `fetch_feed` inside a shortcode, chances are you've hit the bug Stephen described.

However, SimplePie 1.2 had a bug where URLs were incorrectly encoded before the HTTP request was made. This is the most likely cause of your error. WordPress now uses 1.2.1, however, where this bug should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods you use should be identical from PHP viewpoint, I do not see in code any passing by reference or something else that could make a difference.

> but for some reason they are not the last ones

By default there is very considerable caching time 43200 seconds (12 hours). Could it be that this is what getting you undesirable results?

Comment: Ok, here's what I found. The feed is not parsed correctly if there is a "&" in the feed URL. Actually it works in the example I gave, but now I'm populating the feeds array dynamically with this code : `$rss_subscriptions = array();
$terms = get_terms('news_rss','hide_empty=0');
$count = count($terms);
if($count > 0){
 foreach ($terms as $term) {
  array_push($rss_subscriptions,$term->description);
 }
}` The RSS feeds URLs are stored in the descriptions of the taxonomy "news_rss" terms. Somehow in this code, passing "&" into the array makes the fetch_feed(array) not work.

Comment: @mike23 don't think I have any experience with `&` in feed URLs, you might need to pass it through `htmlspecialchars()` or something.

Comment: @mike23: I have rewritten your question because it is a different question now. For clarity: Rarst responded to the original question, which is still available above.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that the & is being converted into &amp; - that's what's happening for me...